# Try / Catch and Async methods

Tags: .net, asynchronous, try-catch

What is the best practice of try\catch exceptions in .net async methods

Socket.BeginSend/Socket.EndSend for example:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Try catch design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849789/try-catch-design)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to handle the error, you may use try..catch.

```
try
{
  // some logic implement
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // error handling
}
finally
{
  // displose the object
}
```

hope this help.

Comment: <Code>try
            {
                client.SendAcync("test message");
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                //code for processing error
            }<Code>

Comment: this not work..exception not processed. i add event in client code that fires on async methods when exception throwed..but i am think that it is not good practice

Answer (score 0):

then you need to define error event handler like:AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(exhandler);

... and define ...

```
    void exhandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught");
    }
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the .EndXXX method with the try/catch.